# VNA Characterization of a non 75Ohm system

Tags: measurement, vna

I'm trying to characterize a 75ohm cable using a VNA.

As it differs from 50Ohm I need to do some adjustments with how I'm measuring but I'm not sure what is considered best practice for that.

I was thinking about two ways :

Using impedance matching pads 50-75ohm then remove the attenuation due to the pads using 2x through deembedding

Or

Get the S parameters then use renormalization

Perhaps none of these are considered as being best practice.

If anyone could drop some knowledge and maybe say pros and cons of those methods it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just put 150 ohms in parallel with the VNA connection to the cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old school RF engineers will use impedance matching pads 50-75 Ohm.

Newbie RF engineers will rely on the VNA, provided that the VNA has that particular math function.

Comment: I tried both, didn't get the exact same results but they were close enough to give a rough idea of the DUT